# Jenkins EmailExt Plugin with both variables and a html body

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

Below is my jenkins pipeline to send a email
The problem is i have some params.variables in my body which i need to use in order for them to be replaced i need to use """ 
I also have a HTML file which i attach in the body, for which i need to use ' '

Is there any way to combine both of them in the body? Below code gives UNEXPECTED TOKEN FILE, if i replace " with ' , then the params variable is not replaced

```
               emailext ( 
                                      mimeType: "text/html",
                                      to: 'srav',
                                      subject: "Job '${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) is waiting for approval",
                                      body: """<p>Hi</p><p>Defect ${params.DE_NUMBER} is waiting for approval</p><p>${FILE,path="/atm/com/def/de_1886.html"}</p><p>Please go to console output of "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}/input">${env.BUILD_URL}input</a>" to <font color="green"> Approve</font> or <font color="red">Reject</font> </p><p>Thank You</p><p>DEVOPS TEAM</p>""",
                                      recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],[$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
                                      )
```

Comment: Did you try `${FILE, path='/atm/com/def/de_1886.html'}`?

Comment: Still the same, doesnt help

Comment: This did work    body: '<p>Hi</p><p>EF ${EF_NUMBER} is waiting for Approval</p><p>${FILE,path="/atm/com/def/de_1886.html"}</p><p>Please go to console output of "<a href="${BUILD_URL}/input">${BUILD_URL}input</a>" to <font color="green"> Approve</font> or <font color="red">Reject</font> </p><p>Thank You</p><p>DEVOPS TEAM</p>',